# Bad autocompletion SublimeCodeIntel

Tags: parameters, autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimecodeintel

I installed SublimeText3 recently. I installed the SublimeCodeIntel package for enable autocompletion for PHP. But, when I've a function with many parameters, it doesn't show the parameters correctly.

[image]

In the area with blue background, in "$ord...variaveis", a part of the parameter $ordenacao is hidden, like a part of the next parameter. The correct is to show "$ordenacao, $tipos_variaveis" instead of "$ord...variaveis". In functions with few parameters, all works fine. But in a function like this, with many parameters, this problem occur. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If the text on a line is too long to fit in the window, it is shortened by adding `...` in the middle. As you can see, there is no way of making the window wider.

From a general programming perspective, if you find yourself writing functions that require more than 3 or 4 arguments, you may be able to refactor the function into 2 or more separate ones, calling one from inside the other. Of course, this may not always be possible, but it is certainly something to consider.

Comment: my functions generally have few arguments, but there is some few exceptions. In PHP Designer, the code completion is different, then I thought that it was a bug. Thanks for your reply.